# helping inserting entries to Azure DB

Tags: javascript, git, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-sql-database

Im just starting out using Azure and i have minimal experience with SQL, so I'm a little confused. I set up my Azure Webapp to pull from a Git repository on bitbucket. I successfully linked those two together, and pushes made to bitbucket update my site. What I am having trouble doing is linking my database on Azure to this site, so that I can make data entry forms and insert that info as records onto this database. Im just starting out simple to learn the basics. I have a table names Users with the elements, id(which is set up as IDENTITY so it sequentially creates a unique id number), username, password, and email. I can pull the info from the HTML document and everything just fine, but how do I correctly link my DB and its tables using HTML, js, and azure? Ill post any additional info that will be necessary, i dont even know where to begin on this really.

Ill also add im using Visual Studio for creating tables and entities and most DB management.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How to access your database depends on the database you are using and the server side programming language. From the tags you used in your question I assume you are using the mysql database provided by clear db through the Azure Management Portal. You can not access your database right from JS. As you are using VS I guess you are using asp.net on the server side. If using asp.net this article might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If you created a ms sql database through the SQL Database service in MS Azure you also need to check the firewall settings to allow access from your app.

Comment: To be honest, I dont know what Im using. I have a small bit of experience writing code for an sql server, but never set one up before. Your other assumptions are correct, i set up my DB through azure management portal, and I am using VS to create tables and such in my DB. I have never used asp.net before so I will check out that out. Can i still write my functions in javascript or will that not be possible? And yes, i did allow firewall access already.

Comment: You can probably write most of your code in javascript on the client side, but this depends on your applications architecture. If you want to save data in your database you should have a look a different server side technologies like asp.net, node.js or php. You could just use them to create web services to talk to from with javascript. The other option is to use a technology that generates the server side and webservices for you, like azure mobile services. But you should first work through the basic architecture patterns for web applications.

Comment: thank you for the info, I found a guide specifically targetting new users wanting to set up ASP.net applications with azure, so I am going to test those out and see if they will work for me. Just to finalize my understanding a bit, javascript is for browser side functions while ASP.net is for DB connections and manipulation? And I can try and make them work together by passing data from ASP.net application to js functions?

Comment: Yes, you use javascript on the client / browser side and ASP.Net on the server side. Depending on the architecture of your app you can develop you business logic / functions in js or asp.net. When using a database you would use asp.net to insert / read to and from the database and expose that data through web services. These services can then be consumed by you js functions. You should check out asp.net web api on how to easily develop web services with asp.net.

Comment: I want to thank you for your help so far, but I am still struggling with this. I seem to be taking steps backwards, not forwards. I can no longer seem to figure out how to properly link my bitbucket, visual studios, and azure together, as well as still not being able to do anything to my DB. Is there anything you can suggests (a guide/tutorial) to help me through the basics. I just want to be able to develop my site on visual studios, have it save the project on bit bucket, and then publish it through azure, while using a SQL database created through azure. Any tips/links/etc. for beginners?

Comment: @[Joseph Ebey], do you want to set up a Skype call to work on this? Find me at [codefoster.com/me](http://codefoster.com/me) and send me an email so we can set something up.